# MongoDB - Branch And Switch Case to check if element in sub array are true or false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is My Schema **

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const stepsSchema = new Schema({
    oid: { type: String },
    wid:  { type: String },
    tid:  { type: String },
    flow: {type: Object},
    actionFlow: [[{id: {type:String}, isPass: {type: Boolean}}]],      // this will run similar to the input state memangment
    stepHistory: [{type:String}],
    currentStepIndex: {type: Number}
}) 

stepsSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator); 

stepsSchema.index({tid: 1})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Steps", stepsSchema);
```

**This is my mongo query**

```
steps = await Steps.findOneAndUpdate(
        { tid: tid },
        [{
         $set: {
         currentStepIndex:
          {  
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: { arrayElemAt: [`actionFlow`, `$currentStepIndex`] ***** NEED TO ADD SOMETHIGN ELSE HERE TO CHECK FOR ISPASS ELEMENT TRUE},
                  then: 10,
                },
                {
                  case: { arrayElemAt: [`actionFlow`, `$currentStepIndex`] ***** NEED TO ADD SOMETHIGN ELSE HERE TO CHECK FOR ISPASS ELEMENT FALSE },
                  then: -10,
                },
              ],
              default: '$currentStepElement',
            },
          },
        }
  }],
```

The result I am looking for is if all elements "isPass" within the subarray of the actionFlow[currentStepIndex] are true then we increment the value of currentStepIndex

The same as above but if both false we decrement the current value of currentStepIndex

default value should not change the value of currentStepElement.

Comment: I'm not a _"mongooser"_ so my questions may be very naive... What is the problem? ... `steps` doesn't have the value you expect? `actionFlow` is an array of arrays?  What  is `currentStepElement`?  What do you expect ``arrayElemAt: [`actionFlow`, `$currentStepIndex`]`` to be?

Comment: arrayElemAt: [`actionFlow`, `$currentStepIndex`]  this bit of code is not correct (I have made edits to my question)

I need to add some other code to this to check if all of the isPass object elements within the array returned from  "arrayElemAt: [`actionFlow`, `$currentStepIndex`]" are iether true or false. 

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Would you show a couple of example documents?

Comment: What if I use $project to get the array elements at actionFlow with index of currentStepIndex

 $project : {currentStepsArray: {arrayElemAt: [`$actionFlow`, $currentStepIndex]}},


Then pass that value down into the switch case block like this:

case: {$currentStepsArray: {$all : { $elemMatch : {isPass: true}}}},

Comment: @MichaelRatcliffe What is the objective of your query? Increment `currentStepIndex` by 10 for every `actionFlow` with `isPass` at `true` and decrement it by 10 for every `actionFlow` with `isPass` at `false`?

Comment: Action flow is an array with nested arrays:   [[{id: 1, isPass: false}],[{id: 2, isPass: false},{id: 3, isPass: false},],[]]

The goal is to check if currentStepIndex should incrament or decrement.

Using currentStepindex to identify which nested array of Actionflow to look at I then want to check if the objects within have the isPass object all set to true or false.

If alltrue then currentstepindex incraments.
If all false then currentstepindex decrements,

Comment: What is `currentStepElement`?  It's in your `findOneAndUpdate` pipeline but I don't see it in the schema.

Comment: I worked out a better way. I adjusted my schema to get rid of the arrays in arrays :)